# Android remote mouse: use data connection instead of WiFi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, remote-desktop, mouse, android

I've tried various Android remote mice apps that all require WiFi:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.djpsoft.remote&hl=en
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iandrobot.andromouse.lite&hl=en
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.negusoft.ucontrol&hl=en

However my WiFi provider seems to be blocking necessary ports or something.

The other alternative - and I do this in my own apps - is a simple socket connection for phone/PC communication, and I tether my phone's data to the PC. However all of these remote mouse apps want "WiFi" in particular, and thus I can't tether and use my phone's data connection.

Is there a solution here? Maybe I can check some wifi settings or something (I already tried turned off my PC firewall). I really don't want to have to remake a remote mouse app for obvious reasons.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

They work on a link between PC and Android device over wifi. I don't think it is provider related as its a local connection. Possibilities are wifi settings and pc settings are off.

Start with pinging you cell phone from PC. You can get IP of your cellphone in settings/wifi. Use windows cmd command "ping" to make sure a connection could be made between PC to mobile device.Usage is simple, "ping cellphoneip" If so try vice versa by using [a android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mm.network&hl=tr). You can find PC is by typing ipconfig in cmd. You can open cmd by typing cmd in run dialog of windows.

It both pings are successful, [try opening ports in windows and router firewalls.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/open-a-port-in-windows-firewall)

Hope it helps